# How to change the unusual font size of Table of Contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, fontsize

Below picture shows my table of contents

The title size (the word, Contents) is very big, maybe `Huge`. I never set it as `Huge` and I searched the whole LaTeX file, there is no the word "huge" at all.

And the number is start with 0, for example "0.1 Introduction", not the normal "1 Introduction"

Below is the only code related with ToC

```
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
.
.
.
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents
```

What problem it can be?

PS: I tried to use `\usepackage{xpatch}`, but this one does not work

I use report

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,leqno,twoside]{report}
```

Thanks everyone! I changed report to article, the problem is gone!

[image]

Comment: Which document class are you using? The odd numbering of the sections may occur because in the `book` and `report` classes, sections are only the second-highest "structural elements" of the text (`chapter` being the highest).

Comment: `\usepackage[titles,subfigure]{tocloft}`; however, if you use `report`, you should use `\chapter{Introduction}` and not `\section{Introduction}`.

Comment: Think of the huge title as a free bonus.  Like "As a free bonus we sent your name and telephone number to over 200 telemarketers."

Comment: I think `\renewcommand\printtoctitle[1]{\Large #1}` could also work.

Comment: Ever thought of using a KOMA-class? It's pretty straight forward there using the key-value `headings=small`.

Comment: @postit Please answer your own question if you have found a good solution. If you think, this topic will not help other in future, just delete your question in order to close this issue. Thank you.

Comment: nonstandard-toc, no example, not reproducable. unregistered user, guessworkk involved, old -> unclear